# Remove images from the_content

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to show only content with all paragraphs (possibly divs,...) but with no attached images.

I had some success with:

```
echo preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '',get_the_content());
```

But it removes paragraphs not just images..
Any idea why?

Comment: Before I posted I made research but as I said - this preg_replace also removes <p>

Comment: No, it does not. Did you actually tested the accepted answer from the duplicate. The code you are using also does not remove p tags, p tags has not yet being added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not removing the p tags: they have not yet been added as `get_the_content` returns the unfiltered content. You can manually add the p tags using [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).

```
$unfiltered = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '',get_the_content());
$filtered = wpautop($unfiltered);

echo $filtered;
```